# How to compare items in two lists of lists by matrix positions? Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am trying to compare two lists of lists `x` and `a`. For example:

```
x = [[10, 11], [14, 12]]
a = [[9, 10], [10, 11], [11, 12], [12, 13], [13, 14], [14, 15], [15, 16]]
```

Specifically, I want to count in how many lists there is an element in `x` that is equal to or larger than the element in `a` that is in the same position. Please note, there can be any number of items in the lists and there can be any number of lists in the lists of lists `x` and `a`.

```
Roughly put, if x and a where only lists:
    
x = | x1, x2 |
a = | a1, a2 |

Then check: x1 >= a1, x2 >= a2. If any of these is True, count +1 else count +0.
```

However, in my situation, `x` and `a` are not simple lists but *lists of lists*. So if the numbers in `x` and `a` are replaced by their matrix position indices, we get:

```
x = [[x1_1, x1_2], [x2_1, x2_2]]
a = [[a1_1, a1_2], [a2_1, a2_2], [a3_1, a3_2], [a4_1, a4_2], [a5_1, a5_2], [a6_1, a6_2], [a7_1, a7_2]]
```

So now, the specific comparison I want to do is as follows:

```
If:
x1_1 >= a1_1
OR # This is important, it does not have to be AND. One is enough to count +1.
x1_2 >= a1_2
Then: count + 1
Else: count + 0

If:
x1_1 >= a2_1
OR
x1_2 >= a2_2
Then: count + 1
Else: count + 0

If:
x1_1 >= a3_1
OR
x1_2 >= a3_2
Then: count + 1
Else: count + 0

Etc.

Repeat the same for [x2_1, x2_2].
```

The result I am expecting from the example is: `(2, 6)`

It seemed to me that this could be done in a straightforward way like:

```
list_3 = []
for j in a:
    for i in x:
        list_3.append(j > i)
print(list_3)
```

Or using a list comprehension:

```
def touch(x, a):
    return [[all([asel > xsubel for xsubel in xel for asel in ael]) for ael in a].count(False) for xel in x ]
touching = touch(x, a)
print(touching)
```

But somehow I am not getting the expected output `(2, 6)`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using two for loops on both the lists will work

```
x = [[10, 11], [14, 12]]
a = [[9, 10], [10, 11], [11, 12], [12, 13], [13, 14], [14, 15], [15, 16]]

ans=[]
for i in x:
    c=0
    for j in a:
        if(i[0]>=j[0] or i[1]>=j[1]):
            c=c+1
    ans.append(c)
print(ans)
[2,6]
```

as you asked about the generalised form I think this will work

```
ans=[]
for i in x:
    c=0
    for j in a:
        for x in range(len(j)):
            if(i[x]>=j[x]):
                c=c+1
                break
    ans.append(c)
print(ans)
```

Comment: Siddhant, what if the lists ```x``` and ```a``` contain not 2 elements but ```n``` elements? Can the expression ```if(i[0]>=j[0] or i[1]>=j[1]):``` be generalised?

Comment: if the elements of both the lists x and a are of same length we can use one more for loop before the if statement to compare all the elements of I and j respectively.

Comment: Yes, lists inside ```a``` always have the same number of items in them as the lists in ```x```.