# How to compare items in lists of lists by index position using a condition? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, list, conditional-statements

I am comparing two lists of lists `x` and `a`. The items in the lists in `a` must be higher than those with the same index position in the lists in `x`. If not, that list must be thrown out of `a`. A counter tracks how many lists in `a` meet the condition for each list in `x`.

With comparing items in `a` vs. `x` by index position I mean:

```
If x = [[a, b], [c, d]]
And a = [[A, B], ... [...]]

Then compare A only with a, and B with only b. Then compare A only to c, B only to d, etc.
```

**I have the following code, which works when the condition is set to `>=` but not when reversed to `<`.** I have been helped by answers on this forum here: [How to compare items in two lists of lists by matrix positions? Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62755507/how-to-compare-items-in-two-lists-of-lists-by-matrix-positions-python). But no post answers my question fully. The solution is probably simple and staring me in the face, but I just cannot figure out how to fix this. **Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?** I would be very grateful if someone has a solution.

```
x = [[10, 11], [14, 12]]
a = [[9, 10], [10, 11], [11, 12], [12, 13], [13, 14], [14, 15], [15, 16]]

list = []
ans=[]
for i in x: # for every Barrier path i in x
    c=0
    lis = []
    for j in a: # for every stock price path j in a
        for z in range(len(j)):
            if(i[z]>=j[z]):
                c=c+1
                lis.append(j)
                break
    ans.append(c)
    list.append(lis)
```

The results are as expected:

```
ans: [2, 6]
list: [[[9, 10], [10, 11]], [[9, 10], [10, 11], [11, 12], [12, 13], [13, 14], [14, 15]]]
```

**However, with the same code and only the condition reversed from >= to <, the result is not as expected.**

```
x = [[10, 11], [14, 12]]
a = [[9, 10], [10, 11], [11, 12], [12, 13], [13, 14], [14, 15], [15, 16]]

list = []
ans=[]
for i in x: # for every Barrier path i in x
    c=0
    lis = []
    for j in a: # for every stock price path j in a
        for z in range(len(j)):
            if(i[z]<j[z]):
                c=c+1
                lis.append(j)
                break
    ans.append(c)
    list.append(lis)
```

ans: `[5, 4]` Expected: `[5, 1]`

list: `[[[11, 12], [12, 13], [13, 14], [14, 15], [15, 16]], [[12, 13], [13, 14], [14, 15], [15, 16]]]`
Expected: `[[[11, 12], [12, 13], [13, 14], [14, 15], [15, 16]], [[15, 16]]]`

When flipping the logical condition, I expect results that are the reverse of the answer above but they are not. Any suggestions how to change the code to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for:

```
def compare_lists(list1,list2, key = lambda x, y: x>=y, key2 = any):
    s = [[i for i in list2 if key2([key(m,n) for m,n in zip(k,i)])] for k in list1] 
    return {"ans" : [len(i) for i in s], "list" : s}
```

Below are the results with different keys:

```
print(compare_lists(x, a, lambda x,y: x<y,all)) # all to be less than
{'ans': [5, 1], 'list': [[[11, 12], [12, 13], [13, 14], [14, 15], [15, 16]], [[15, 16]]]}

print(compare_lists(x, a))# any to be greater than
{'ans': [2, 6], 'list': [[[9, 10], [10, 11]], [[9, 10], [10, 11], [11, 12], [12, 13], [13, 14], [14, 15]]]}

print(compare_lists(x, a, lambda x,y: x<y)) #any to be less than
{'ans': [5, 4], 'list': [[[11, 12], [12, 13], [13, 14], [14, 15], [15, 16]], [[12, 13], [13, 14], [14, 15], [15, 16]]]}

print(compare_lists(x, a, lambda x,y: x>=y,all)) # all to be greater than
{'ans': [2, 3], 'list': [[[9, 10], [10, 11]], [[9, 10], [10, 11], [11, 12]]]}
```

Comment: This is really impressive and a different solution than I expected. Thank you so much.